# How do I add a File Type Association in a Windows Phone 8.1 app manifest?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to access files in the `KnownFolders.MusicLibrary`with the following code.

```
    internal async void Update()
    {
        StorageFolder rootFolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
        ScanFolder(rootFolder);
    }

    private async void ScanFolder(StorageFolder storageFolder)
    {
        var items = await storageFolder.GetItemsAsync();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item is StorageFolder)
            {
                ScanFolder(item as StorageFolder);
            }
            else if (item is StorageFile)
            {
                var fs = new FileStream(item.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                < ... snip ... >
            }
        }
    }
```

I have the `MusicLibrary` Capability checked so that I can use `KnownFolders.MusicLibrary`.
This doesn't seem to grant me file access to the library though because I get the following error:

```
+       [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]    

{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Data\Users\Public\Music\tmp' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at MusicTrackerPhone.Library.<ScanFolder>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__3(Object state)}    System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

It's not possible to add a `FileType Association` via the GUI (nor is the node allowed in the xml).

[image]

[image]

How do I add the needed declarations for my app?

The complete Package.appxmanifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest" xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest" xmlns:m3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/manifest" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest">
  <Identity Name="aad31163-0d67-49ba-b569-80ff4d773fa0" Publisher="CN=Benjamin" Version="1.0.0.0" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="2e54a5f6-5319-4dd2-9bad-1fe5290a0eeb" PhonePublisherId="1b03f58e-5a39-414f-9324-2cab834debfd" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>MusicTrackerPhone</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Benjamin</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Prerequisites>
    <OSMinVersion>6.3.1</OSMinVersion>
    <OSMaxVersionTested>6.3.1</OSMaxVersionTested>
  </Prerequisites>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="x2e54a5f6y5319y4dd2y9bady1fe5290a0eebx" Executable="AGHost.exe" EntryPoint="MainPage.xaml">
      <m3:VisualElements DisplayName="MusicTrackerPhone" Square150x150Logo="Assets\SquareTile150x150.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Description="MusicTrackerPhone" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646">
        <m3:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="Assets\SquareTile71x71.png">
        </m3:DefaultTile>
        <m3:SplashScreen Image="Assets\Splashscreen.png" />
      </m3:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <FileTypeAssociation Name=".mp3">
            <DisplayName>mp3</DisplayName>
            <SupportedFileTypes>
              <FileType ContentType="audio/mp3">.mp3</FileType>
            </SupportedFileTypes>
          </FileTypeAssociation>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="musicLibrary" />
    <Capability Name="removableStorage" />
  </Capabilities>
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>AgHostSvcs.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="AgHost.BackgroundTask" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange thing (it concerns only WP8.1 Silverlight), but as I've checked, it is possible to add *FileType Associations* via xaml editor: right click on *package.appxmanifest* file, select <kbd>View code F7</kbd>. Find section `<Extensions>` in your `<Application` (probably just after `</m3:VisualElements>`) and add the first *FileType Association* manually:

```
  </m3:VisualElements>
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
      <FileTypeAssociation Name=".mp3">
        <DisplayName>mp3</DisplayName>
        <SupportedFileTypes>
          <FileType ContentType="audio/mp3">.mp3</FileType>
        </SupportedFileTypes>
      </FileTypeAssociation>
    </Extension>
    // other extensions
  </Extensions>
```

Once you add the first, the next *FileType Associations* you will be able to add via GUI - from now it will be available in *Supported Declarations*.

[image]

Comment: Please see the question. I mentioned that adding the node to the xml does not work. Added a screenshot.

Comment: @BenjaminDiele I've just checked it. Wait, I'll try to share an example.

Comment: I apparently added the node to the wrong parent. You are correct that adding an `Extensions` node in the `<Applications>` node is the way to go. Now I still need to solve the Access Denied exceptions.

Comment: @BenjaminDiele Add Capabilities Music Library, Removable Storage and see if that helps.

Comment: see the updated question. I added the complete Package.appxmanifest (which already had those capabilities).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56297/discussion-between-romasz-and-benjamin-diele).

Comment: Note that when debugging in VS, if you are making changes to your fileTypeAssociations in your mainfest file, YOU MUST UNINSTALL the app on the device or emulator before you hit Debug, otherwise the changes will not be registered.

Comment: @user925327 Thanks for the comment, it may help some other people. I haven't played with that so much to encounter this issue.

Answer (score 0):

NO Need to add .mp3 in file association it is reserved and will be ignored. You can access only SD card library not on phone memory.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.