# Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 App Write Access to SD Card

Tags: sd-card, windows-phone-8.1

With the arrival of Windows Phone 8.1, it is now able to have write access to the SD card of a Windows Phone 8.1 device:

[MSDN: Windows Phone 8.1 Access SD Card](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611857.aspx)

You specify the **removableStorage** capability and register for desired file extensions you need to handle, and you are able to view SD card's files and folders.

My question is how you create a new file inside the SD card, if it does not exist? I have managed to do it with the following after looking into the private member **m_internalFolderPath** of ExternalStorageFolder:

```
File.Open("D:\\test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

But is it OK to use **"D:"** as the root path for SD card? I can't find any reference this online. Is letter "D:" device/vendor specific or should I trust it as the letter for SD card?

Comment: Don't trust the SD card is always going to be mounted as D:. The first place you are going to see it break will be the emulator (which under some modes will mount a debug volume as D: and SD card as F:) and phones are not guaranteed to mount the SD card as D: although most (all?) currently do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating file via a path beginning with `D:`

```
File.Create(@"D:\test.txt");
```

will work in most cases, but it's not said anywhere that OS will assign letter `D` for the SD card (thought in fact I haven't seen other). But to be sure, you can always access SD card via *StorageFolder*:

```
StorageFolder SDDevice = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
StorageFolder sdCard = (await SDDevice.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
await sdCard.CreateFileAsync("test.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
```

To make those above work you need to have declared *Capabilities* and *FileTypeAssociations* in *package.appxmanifest* file.

There is [a little issue with VS and Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24416244/2681948) - you will need to add *FileTypeAssociations* manually.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I have already tried using KnownFolders.RemoveableDevices but I get "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))" although I have set the removableStorage capability. Project is Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1, any ideas?

Comment: @gmag You need to [add FIleTypeAssociations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24416482/2681948). I thought you have done that already while you have written: *and register for desired file extensions...*

Comment: After I read your other post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416244/how-do-i-add-a-file-type-association-in-a-windows-phone-8-1-app-manifest) I have been able to use the proposed solution using KnownFolders.RemoveableDevices. In fact the problem was that I had manually created the file type associations in Package.appxmanifest but not inside "Applications" section! Thank you for your support :)

Answer (score 2):

Everything written above is correct, but there are a couple of gotcha's here which you need to know about. I've been ripping my hair out over the last few days with a few intermittent problems, most notable being an ACCESS_DENIED error when simply calling Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices with everything set up as documented.

1...Firstly, its important to understand that you need at least ONE fileTypeAssociation in your manifest to even call the first line Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.
2...Secondly, to register any changes to your fileTypeAssociations in your mainfest file, YOU MUST UNINSTALL the app on the device or emulator before you hit Debug (this caused me hours of problems, mainly because I wasn't convinced that a fileTypeAssociation was needed just to get a handle to the SD card).

Hope this helps save a few locks of hair.